# Android : Single Tab Having multiple activity

Tags: android, tabbar

I need single tab to have multple activity

Example:

When I Click Button on ShowGrid Activity it needs to traverse to Medicine Activity with the tabbar indicating same tab

### ShopGrid & Medicine on Single Tab

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ShopGrid.class); 
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Store").setIndicator("Store")  
              .setContent(intent);  
tabHost.addTab(spec);  

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Medicine.class); 
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Store").setIndicator("Store")  
              .setContent(intent);  
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```